# Sending Current Cell Value in dataURL

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, free-jqgrid

Using jqGrid 4.15.6-pre - free jqGrid

In my colModel I am populating a cell with dataURL. I want to send the current cell value to the server with the URL. The following sends the parameter but the value(this.value) is undefined.

```
colModel:[
        {name:'id', index:'id', width:80, hidden: true, editable: true, editoptions:{ readonly:'readonly'}, editrules:{edithidden:true}, formoptions:{rowpos:1, colpos:1,label:"Index#:"}},
        {name:'crrstatus', index:'crrstatus', hidden: true, editable: true, editrules:{edithidden:true}, formoptions:{rowpos:2, colpos:1,label:"Current Queue:", elmsuffix: " "},
         edittype: "select",
            editoptions: { dataUrl: '/QMSWebApp/CustomerReturnRecordsControllerServletV8?lifecycle=customerReturnStatusOptionsLessInitialized&currentQueue='+this.value,
            selectFilled: function (options) {
                $(options.elem).select2({
                    dropdownCssClass: 'ui-widget ui-jqdialog zclassX2',
                    width: 300
                });
        }}},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it this way in jqGrid (suppose free-jqgrid too), since the **this.value** is set when the colModel is created and it is undefined to this time. In order to do what you want you will need to use a dataUrl as function and pass the value to it like this:

```js
colModel:[
        {name:'id', index:'id', width:80, hidden: true, editable: true, editoptions:{ readonly:'readonly'}, editrules:{edithidden:true}, formoptions:{rowpos:1, colpos:1,label:"Index#:"}},
        {name:'crrstatus', index:'crrstatus', hidden: true, editable: true, editrules:{edithidden:true}, formoptions:{rowpos:2, colpos:1,label:"Current Queue:", elmsuffix: " "},
         edittype: "select",
            editoptions: { dataUrl: function ( rowId, value, name) {
                return '/QMSWebApp/CustomerReturnRecordsControllerServletV8?lifecycle=customerReturnStatusOptionsLessInitialized&currentQueue='+value,
            }
            selectFilled: function (options) {
                $(options.elem).select2({
                    dropdownCssClass: 'ui-widget ui-jqdialog zclassX2',
                    width: 300
                });
        }}},
```

Comment: Thanks@Tony. What if I want to use another column value in my dataURL string? Say the value if the ID coulmn.

Comment: I got it to by using this: &crrType='+$("#customerReturnqueue").getRowData(rowId)['crrType']

Comment: Now my challenge is after the edit form displays, I change the value of the crrType dropdown how do I refresh the crrstatus dropdown on the fly?